# Pixel 5 contacts app does not work after activating phone

Tags: google-pixel, google-contacts

I just bought a new Pixel 5. I successfully transferred my contacts from my old phone via bluetooth before activating the pixel. After getting a new SIM card and transferring  to a new carrier my contacts are empty. There is no option to add new contacts. If I try to transfer contacts via bluetooth, like I had done before, then the contacts app will crash. It will take about 10 seconds to open, and then just opens a blank black screen. If I open a text conversation and click 'add to contacts' the screen just gets a little darker and nothing happens.

The google support site suggests clearing the cache for the app, but there is no such option for this app.

It cannot be that the phone is too full or has too many apps running. It is a brand new phone with no additional software installed.

The contacts app seemed to work fine before activating the phone under a new carrier.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out within seconds of posting.

It turns out the contacts app does not work with Google-Play disabled, which I had disabled just to get it out of the way.

Comment: Good to know that you found the solution by yourself. I noticed a few apps start with "Google Play" on my Pixel. Did you mean "Google Play Store"? Could you [edit] and clarify that? Thanks!